# Image equal to kernel

Tags: linear-transformations

Define the general formula of linear transformation $f:\mathbb{R}^{4}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that $Imf=Kerf$.
Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas by you? Did you try some example?

Comment: I thought $f(x,y,z,w)=(x,y,0,0)$ but i am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the well known rank-nullity theorem $\text{dim(Ker(}f\text{))+dim(Im(}f\text{))=dim(}\mathbb{R}^4)$ to establish that (since the kernel is equal to the image) the dimension of both the kernel and the image is $2$. Can you pick it up from here?